# Shell script i have code using for loop

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh

i=1
for day in mon tue wed thu fri
do
    echo "weekday $((i++)) : $day"

        if [ $i -eq 3 ];then
        break;
        fi
done
```

I used debug mode to check how this script it will work

> - i=1
> - for day in mon tue wed thu fri sat sun
> - echo 'weekday 1 : mon' weekday 1 : mon
> - '[' 2 -eq 3 ']'
> - for day in mon tue wed thu fri sat sun
> - echo 'weekday 2 : tue' weekday 2 : tue
> - '[' 3 -eq 3 ']'
> - break

Here I am not understand variable (i) how it will work form staring to end. Could you please give me some explanation about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(first you are mixing syntax from bash (e.g. `$((...))`, while using `#!/bin/sh` as the interpreter so it is difficult to say with certainty what will happen.) If you are getting numeric evaluation from `$((...))`, your shell (whichever that may be) is interpreting the `$((...))` correctly

What is happening, and what you would expect in bash, etc. is that `i` is being incremented explicitly when you call `$((i++))` inside the loop. When you begin the script, you set `i=1` and it maintains that value until you begin to loop. When you start your loop, e.g.:

```
for day in mon tue wed thu fri
do
```

The loop variable is `day`, so `day` will take the values `mon`, `tue`, `wed`, `thu` and `fri` on each successive iteration through the loop. `i` however will increase by `1` on each iteration:

```
echo "weekday $((i++)) : $day"
```

What is happening is `$((i++))` is the same as `i=$((i+1))`, (or `i=$(expr $i + 1)` if you are more familiar with that). The arithmetic syntax you are using can be used for tests itself or for arithmetic. If called *without* the leading `'$'`, the mathematical expression between the `((..))` is evaluated and all variable values updated.

If called with the leading `'$'`, then the same evaluation/update occurs, but the value is dereferenced and the value of the expression is made available at the point of dereference, no different that doing the same to a variable. (e.g. `i=1; echo "i $i"`).

In your case you are both evaluating (with the post-increment operator) and dereferencing with the `'$'` in `echo "weekday $((i++)) : $day"`. So you would expect it to output:

```
weekday 1 : mon
weekday 2 : tue
```

as `i` is updated during each loop until `i=3`, then you would expect the loop to be exited with:

```
    if [ $i -eq 3 ];then
        break;
    fi
```

Which is what occurs. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

**Note:** The `$((...))` syntax is not part of the POSIX shell specification, so I would not expect your script to be portable using `#!/bin/sh`. In reality many distribution simply softlink `/bin/sh -> /bin/bash`, so I suspect that is what is happening in your case.